# 3D models not rendering in phone view due to load on mobile browser

Tags: reactjs, three.js

I have my react based web app in which I have incorporated three 3D models .These models work perfectly fine on desktop but the problem is all of them do not render on the mobile view . If one is rendered the other will break .There is no issue in the css code. Models are in GLTF format.[This is the deployed website](https://portfolio-website-nu-liart.vercel.app/). I think that the problem might be due to some issue on phone's browser rendering limitations. How can I resolve the issue.

#### ALL 3 MODELS CODE

Earth.js

```
import React from "react";
import { Suspense } from "react";
import { Canvas } from "@react-three/fiber";
import { OrbitControls, Preload, useGLTF } from "@react-three/drei";
import CanvasLoader from "../Loader";
import { EarthCanvas } from ".";

const Earth = () => {
  const earth = useGLTF("./planet/scene.gltf");
  return <primitive object={earth.scene} scale={2.5} />;
};

const EarthCanvass = () => {
  return (
    <Canvas
      shadows
      frameloop="demand"
      gl={{ preserveDrawingBuffer: true }}
      camera={{
        fov: 45,
        near: 0.1,
        far: 200,
        position: [-4, 3, 6],
      }}
    >
      <Suspense fallback={<CanvasLoader />}>
        <OrbitControls
          autoRotate
          enableZoom={false}
          maxPolarAngle={Math.PI / 2}
          minPolarAngle={Math.PI / 2}
        />
        <Earth />
      </Suspense>
    </Canvas>
  );
};

export default EarthCanvass;
```

Computer.js

```
import { Suspense, useEffect, useState } from "react";
import { Canvas } from "@react-three/fiber";
import { OrbitControls, Preload, useGLTF } from "@react-three/drei";
import CanvasLoader from "../Loader";

const ComputersCanvas = () => {
  const [isMobile, setIsMobile] = useState(false);

  useEffect(() => {
    const mediaQuery = window.matchMedia("(max-width:500px)");
    setIsMobile(mediaQuery.matches);
    const handleMediaQueryChange = (event) => {
      setIsMobile(event.matches);
    };

    mediaQuery.addEventListener("change", handleMediaQueryChange);
    return () => {
      mediaQuery.removeEventListener("change", handleMediaQueryChange);
    };
  }, []);

  return (
    <Canvas
      className="mt-5"
      frameloop="demand"
      shadows
      camera={{ position: [20, 3, 5], fov: 25 }}
      gl={{ preserveDrawingBuffer: true }}
    >
      <Suspense fallback={<CanvasLoader />}>
        <OrbitControls
          enableZoom={false}
          maxPolarAngle={Math.PI / 2}
          minPolarAngle={Math.PI / 2}
        />
        <Computers isMobile={isMobile} />
      </Suspense>
      <Preload all />
    </Canvas>
  );
};

const Computers = ({ isMobile }) => {
  const computer = useGLTF("./desktop_pc/scene.gltf");
  return (
    <mesh>
      <hemisphereLight intensity={0.15} groundColor="black" />
      <pointLight intensity={1} />
      <spotLight
        position={[-20, 50, 10]}
        angle={0.12}
        penumbra={1}
        intensity={1}
        castShadow
        shadow-mapSize={1024}
      />
      <primitive
        object={computer.scene}
        scale={isMobile ? 0.7 : 0.75}
        position={isMobile ? [0, -3, -2.2] : [0, -3.25, -1.5]}
        rotation={isMobile ? [-0.01, -0.2, -0.1] : [-0.01, -0.2, -0.1]}
      />
    </mesh>
  );
};

export default ComputersCanvas;
```

Ball.js

```
import React from "react";
import { Canvas } from "@react-three/fiber";
import {
  Decal,
  Float,
  OrbitControls,
  Preload,
  useTexture,
} from "@react-three/drei";
import { Suspense, useState } from "react";
import CanvasLoader from "../Loader";

const Ball = (props) => {
  const [decal] = useTexture([props.imgUrl]);
  return (
    <Float>
      <ambientLight intensity={0.25} floatIntensity={2} speed={1.75} />
      <directionalLight position={[0, 0, 0.05]} />
      <mesh castShadow receiveShadow scale={2.75}>
        <icosahedronGeometry args={[1, 1]} />
        <meshStandardMaterial
          color="#fff8eb"
          polygonOffset
          polygonOffsetFactor={-5}
          flatShading
        />
        <Decal
          rotation={[2 * Math.PI, 0, 6.25]}
          position={[0, 0, 1]}
          map={decal}
        />
      </mesh>
    </Float>
  );
};

const BallCanvas = ({ icon }) => {
  return (
    <Canvas frameloop="demand" gl={{ preserveDrawingBuffer: true }}>
      <Suspense fallback={<CanvasLoader />}>
        <OrbitControls enableZoom={false} />
        <Ball imgUrl={icon} />
      </Suspense>
      <Preload all />
    </Canvas>
  );
  `your text`;
};

export default BallCanvas;
```

Comment: I get an error in the browser console.. "Computed radius is NaN. The "position" attribute is likely to have NaN values"

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried making low poly versions for mobile?

Import your high-poly model into Blender.

Select the model: Click on it in the 3D view.

Go to the Modifier Properties panel: It's the wrench icon in the Properties window.

Add a Decimate modifier: This modifier can reduce the polygon count while attempting to preserve the overall shape.

Adjust the Ratio parameter: This controls the amount of reduction. Lower values result in fewer polygons.

Apply the modifier: Once you are satisfied with the reduction, click the "Apply" button to make the changes permanent.

Export the simplified model: Use the export options to save the model in a format that Three.js can load, such as GLTF.

Comment: did you use any generative AI at all in the writing of this answer post?